# Laravel 6: Localization lost once page redirects

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I am trying to set up localization on my website. However, when the user clicks on his preferred language, the default redirects function `back()` returns the default value of appLocale.

Request use to change language:

```php
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    @if (app()->getLocale() !== 'en')
        <a href="/en" class="dropdown-item">
        <span>
            <img class="flag" src="{{asset('images/bg/gb.svg')}}" alt=""/> {{__('English')}}
        </span>
        </a>
    @endif
    @if (app()->getLocale() !== 'fr')
        <a href="/fr" class="dropdown-item">
        <span>
            <img class="flag" src="{{asset('images/bg/fr.svg')}}" alt=""/> {{__('Français')}}
         </span>
        </a>
    @endif
</div>
```

**Route**

```php
Route::get('/{locale}', 'LangController@index');
```

**LangController**

```php
class LangController extends Controller
{
    public function index($locale)
    {
        app()->setLocale($locale);

        return back()->permanent();
    }
}
```

When I check the value of the locale through `dd(App::getLocale())` it is set to the new value but once the redirect function is executed, Its value moves back to the default local value from the `config/app`.
Any idea on how to keep the change after redirecting.

Comment: Store the locale in the user session no ?

Comment: I will check the content of the session before and after the translation request.

Comment: Thanks, with that I realized that the **local** attribute is per request so I wrote a middleware that assigns the user's preferred language per request.